# LEFT JOIN doesn't consider ON clause

Tags: mysql, sql

My query below is used to retrieve list of items which has been ordered and returned by the customer. I'm confused with the last join, `ReturnCustomer`, where I want the query to return data with `status = 20` or otherwise it returns `NULL`. Below is my query:

```
SELECT Product.id AS product_id, Product.supplier_product_id AS vip_id, Product.name AS product_name, detailSO.qty, detailRC.return_qty
FROM Product
RIGHT JOIN detailSO ON detailSO.product_id = Product.id
RIGHT JOIN SalesOrder ON SalesOrder.id = detailSO.so_id AND SalesOrder.status >= 20
LEFT JOIN detailRC ON detailRC.sur_key = detailSO.sur_key
LEFT JOIN ReturnCustomer ON ReturnCustomer.id = detailRC.rc_id AND ReturnCustomer.status >= 20
```

If I use `LEFT JOIN`, it doesn't consider about `ReturnCustomer.status >= 20` since it returns all data. On the other hand, if I use `RIGHT JOIN` it will only return data with `ReturnCustomer.status >= 20`,

`LEFT JOIN Result:`

```
P_id    Pp_id   P_name  i_qty   r_qty
P000001 P000001 Item 1  15      1
P000001 P000001 Item 1  5       1
P000002 P000002 Item 2  5       NULL
```

`RIGHT JOIN Result:`

```
P_id    Pp_id   P_name  i_qty   r_qty
P000001 P000001 Item 1  15      1
```

`Expected Result:`

```
P_id    Pp_id   P_name  i_qty   r_qty
P000001 P000001 Item 1  15      1
P000001 P000001 Item 1  5       NULL <-- null since it comes from ReturnCustomer with status = 0
P000002 P000002 Item 2  5       NULL
```

I know maybe I could solve this using nested query, hopefully you guys can provide me a better solution. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
Here is my simplified problem [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9af82/1)..

Comment: Don't confuse us humans, convert to LEFT JOIN only. RIGHT JOIN's are too weird for most people.

Comment: Have you tried moving `status >= 20` to the WHERE clause?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry I already provide a simplified version of my issue on sqlfiddle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a LEFT JOIN b` works exactly like that.. (the `a` will always be present, where `b` may be null)

`ON` works only removing the `b`, where `a` won't be affected..

`WHERE` works by removing rows

so when

```
 A have 1,2,3
 B have 1,2
 C have 1,3
```

when those three left joined, for example:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM A 
 LEFT JOIN B ON A.x = B.x
 LEFT JOIN C ON B.x = C.x
```

it would give:

```
 A B C
 1 1 1
 2 2
 3
```

if the second `LEFT JOIN` joined to `A`, for example:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM A 
 LEFT JOIN B ON A.x = B.x
 LEFT JOIN C ON A.x = C.x
```

it would give:

```
 A B C
 1 1 1
 2 2
 3   3
```

any more criteria on the last `ON` won't remove the B part, since  it's already joined before, any criteria on `WHERE` part will remove whole row.

In your case, if you want to hide the `B` part, you should not use `ON` or `WHERE`, the correct one would be using `CASE WHEN` in the `SELECT` part, for example:

```
SELECT detailSO.product_id
, detailSO.qty
, CASE WHEN RC.id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE detailRC.qty END AS x
FROM SO
LEFT JOIN detailSO ON detailSO.so_id = SO.id
LEFT JOIN detailRC ON detailRC.sur_key = detailSO.sur_key
LEFT JOIN RC ON RC.id = detailRC.rc_id AND RC.status >= 20
WHERE SO.status >= 20
```

Result in sql Fiddle

```
product_id  qty x
P00001      15  1
P00001      5   (null)
P00002      5   (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

this may works

```
SELECT 
  Product.id AS product_id,
  Product.supplier_product_id AS vip_id,
  Product.name AS product_name,
  detailSO.qty,
  detailRC.return_qty 
FROM
  Product 
  RIGHT JOIN detailSO 
    ON detailSO.product_id = Product.id 
  RIGHT JOIN SalesOrder 
    ON SalesOrder.id = detailSO.so_id 
    AND SalesOrder.status >= 20 
  LEFT JOIN detailRC 
    ON detailRC.sur_key = detailSO.sur_key 
  LEFT JOIN ReturnCustomer 
    ON ReturnCustomer.id = detailRC.rc_id 
    WHERE ReturnCustomer.status >= 20
```

Comment: it gives me the same result as using `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the below:

```
SELECT Product.id AS product_id, Product.supplier_product_id AS vip_id,   
       Product.name AS product_name, detailSO.qty, detailRC.return_qty
       FROM Product
       RIGHT JOIN detailSO ON detailSO.product_id = Product.id
       RIGHT JOIN SalesOrder ON SalesOrder.id = detailSO.so_id
       LEFT JOIN detailRC ON detailRC.sur_key = detailSO.sur_key
       LEFT JOIN ReturnCustomer ON ReturnCustomer.id = detailRC.rc_id 
where 
       ReturnCustomer.status >= 20
  AND  SalesOrder.status >= 20
```

Comment: it gives me the same result as using `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: I thing that the problem then is what bakersman suggest, above.
Are you sure you use the corerct isnull syntax?
for ex: 
Where isnull(ReturnCustomer.status,0) >= 20... etc
Apply the same logic to the join too...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is how it evaluates the NULL values.  Try using ISNULL in your ON clause:

```
SELECT Product.id AS product_id, Product.supplier_product_id AS vip_id, Product.name AS product_name, detailSO.qty, detailRC.return_qty
FROM Product
RIGHT JOIN detailSO ON detailSO.product_id = Product.id
RIGHT JOIN SalesOrder ON SalesOrder.id = detailSO.so_id AND SalesOrder.status >= 20
LEFT JOIN detailRC ON detailRC.sur_key = detailSO.sur_key
LEFT JOIN ReturnCustomer ON ReturnCustomer.id = detailRC.rc_id AND ISNULL(ReturnCustomer.status, 0) >= 20
```

Comment: it produces `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'`..

Answer (score 0):

Using nested query gives you desired result

```
 SELECT temp.* from (
      SELECT 
      Product.id AS product_id,
      Product.supplier_product_id AS vip_id,
      Product.name AS product_name,
      detailSO.qty,
      detailRC.return_qty 
    FROM
      Product 
      RIGHT JOIN detailSO 
        ON detailSO.product_id = Product.id 
      RIGHT JOIN SalesOrder 
        ON SalesOrder.id = detailSO.so_id
      LEFT JOIN detailRC 
        ON detailRC.sur_key = detailSO.sur_key 
      LEFT JOIN ReturnCustomer 
        ON ReturnCustomer.id = detailRC.rc_id 

    ) as temp 
     WHERE temp .status >= 20
```

Comment: Thanks.. I don't want to use nested query.. @kokizzu answer already solve my issue.